# Use local decimal separator, but not grouping character, with stringstream

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting and removing commas from integers in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791258/inserting-and-removing-commas-from-integers-in-c)

I want to write double values with the decimal separator as in the current locale, but I do not want it grouped by the grouping character from the current locale. The current approach with

```
stringstream s;
s.imbue(std::locale(""));
```

solves only one of the issues. The current output is like 1,234.567 instead of the wanted 1234.567

How can I change this?

Comment: Of course, my answer to the other question deals with *integer* values but this should work with `float`s as well.

Comment: sounds good to me - I'll give it a try.

Comment: the solution worked - please vote for dirkgently at the thread mentioned before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the help of dirkgently's post [inserting and removing commas from integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791258/inserting-and-removing-commas-from-integers-in-c), I created the following class:

```
class no_grouping : public std::numpunct_byname<char> {
    std::string do_grouping() const { return ""; }

public:
    no_grouping() : numpunct_byname("") {}
};
```

Important here is to derive from numpunkct_byname and initialize it with the constructor parameter "" for the local locale.

Then the stream can easily be imbued with the following code:

```
ostringstream stringBuff;
std::locale locale(std::locale(""),new no_grouping);
stringBuff.imbue(locale);
```

this will remove the grouping, but it will take the decimal separator from the local locale.